# $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\int_{0}^1 (1-x^2)^n} = 0$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\int_{0}^1 (1-x^2)^n} = 0$

**My Attempt :** Now $(1-x^2)^n$   is uniformly convergent to $0$ when $x \in (0 , \delta)$. So $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\int_{\delta}^1 (1-x^2)^n} = 0$. Here $0 < \delta < 1$.
IS it sufficient to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\int_{0}^1 (1-x^2)^n} = 0$ ?

Can anyone please help me ??

Comment: To show something tends to 0 as $n \to \infty$, show for each $\varepsilon > 0$ that it's below $\varepsilon$ for all large enough $n$.  You already showed that if you split the interval of integration at $\delta$ then the integral over $[\delta,1]$ gets arbitrarily small (say, below $\varepsilon/2$) for all large enough $n$. Work out an upper bound on $\int_0^\delta (1 - x^2)^n\,dx$ in terms of $\delta$ that is *independent of* $n$ and then choose $\delta$ to make that upper bound at most $\varepsilon/2$.

Comment: It is a bad habit to omit the $dx$ in the integrals when communicating math to other people (you do it three times in the question and once in the title). Ignoring $dx$ will lead you to make mistakes when using the method of integration by substitution.

Comment: I assume that you wanted to say that $(1-x^2)^n$ uniformly converges to $0$ if $x \in (\delta, 1]$?
Anyway you need an additional argument. In this case you could use the fact that $(1-x^2)^n$ is bounded on $[0, \delta)$. For example the function $f_n (t) = (nt)^{-1}$ also satisfies $\lim_\delta^1 f_n (t) dt = 0$ for every $0 < \delta < 1$ but $\int_0^1 f_n(t) = \infty$ for every $n$.

Comment: For your next problem  try to prove that if $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ is continuous and $I_n=\int_0^1|f(x)|^n dx$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}(I_n)^{1/n}=\max \{|f(x)|: x\in [0,1]\}$. Different problem, but related technique.

Answer (score 2):

Put $Z_n = \int_0^n{(1-x^2)^n dx}$. We have $\forall \epsilon >0$
$$Z_n= \int_0^n{(1-x^2)^n dx} = \int_0^{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{(1-x^2)^n dx}+\int_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}^{1}{(1-x^2)^n dx} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \int_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}^{1}{(1-(\frac{\epsilon}{2})^2)^n dx} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} + (1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{4})^n $$

And we have $\forall n> \frac{\ln (\frac{\epsilon}{2})}{\ln (1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{4})}$, $(1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{4})^n  \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

So, $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N= \frac{\ln (\frac{\epsilon}{2})}{\ln (1-\frac{\epsilon^2}{4})}$ so that $\forall n>N , Z_n < \frac{\epsilon}{2} +\frac{\epsilon}{2} =\epsilon $. We can conclude  $Z_n \longrightarrow 0 $

Comment: Equivalently, let $L= \lim_{m\to \infty}\sup_{n\ge m} Z_n.$ If $k\in (0,1)$ then $0<Z_n\le k+(1-k^2)^n$  so $0\le L\le \lim_{m\to \infty}\sup_{n\ge m} k+(1-k^2)^n=k.$ That is, $\forall k\in (0,1)\, (0\le L\le k);$ therefore $L=0.$

Answer (score 0):

$$I_n=\int_0^1(1-x^2)^ndx$$
$u=1-x^2,du=-2xdx=-2\sqrt{1-u}dx\Rightarrow dx=-2\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u}}$ and so we have:
$$I_n=2\int_0^1\frac{u^n}{\sqrt{1-u}}du$$
now on the lower part we have an issue as $u\to1$ and also on the top $\to1$ but for the rest of the interval it is clear that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u^n}{\sqrt{1-u}}\to0\,\,\,\,u\ne1$$